# Is it possible to modify a .js file from r console?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to modify the content of a .js file in my working directory. I know that I can simply create a blank .js file in the R console using

file.create("test.js")

but how can I write inside from the R console? is there any function in R to do this?

I would like to write something inside the .js file, so I can then execute it with the system() function.

Comment: Just realized that cat was the way to go, I can simply store what i want to write inside the .js file in an R object and then use cat(text, file = "test.js", sep = "\n"). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the file by using the write function.

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/write.html

So you could do something like this:

```
file.create("test.js")

code  <- "alert()"

write(code, file="test.js")
```

As joran pointed out in the comments cat would also work.