# Mixed code unicode and octal/hexadecimal in R

Tags: javascript, r, unicode

I'm setting up a JS script inside the Plotly package from R. I have the following information to run in R.

```
code  <- 'var locale = {
  moduleType: "locale",
  name: "pt-br",
  dictionary: {
    Autoscale: "Escala autom\xe1tica",
    "Box Select": "Sele\xe7\xe3o retangular",
    "Click to enter Colorscale title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo da escala de cor",
    "Click to enter Component A title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do Componente A",
    "Click to enter Component B title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do Componente B",
    "Click to enter Component C title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do Componente C",
    "Click to enter Plot title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do Gr\xe1fico",
    "Click to enter X axis title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do eixo X",
    "Click to enter Y axis title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do eixo Y",
    "Click to enter radial axis title": "Clique para editar o t\xedtulo do eixo radial",
    "Compare data on hover": "Comparar dados ao pairar",
    "Double-click on legend to isolate one trace": "Duplo clique na legenda para isolar uma s\xe9rie",
    "Double-click to zoom back out": "Duplo clique para reverter zoom",
    "Download plot as a png": "Fazer download do gr\xe1fico como imagem (png)",
    "Download plot": "Fazer download do gr\xe1fico",
    "Edit in Chart Studio": "Editar no Chart Studio",
    "IE only supports svg. Changing format to svg.": "IE suporta apenas svg. Alterando formato para svg",
    "Lasso Select": "Sele\xe7\xe3o de la\xe7o",
    "Orbital rotation": "Rota\xe7\xe3o orbital",
    Pan: "Mover",
    "Produced with Plotly": "Criado com o Plotly",
    Reset: "Restaurar",
    "Reset axes": "Restaurar eixos",
    "Reset camera to default": "Restaurar c\xe2mera para padr\xe3o",
    "Reset camera to last save": "Restaurar c\xe2mera para \xfaltima salva",
    "Reset view": "Restaurar vis\xe3o",
    "Reset views": "Restaurar vis\xf5es",
    "Show closest data on hover": "Exibir dado mais pr\xf3ximo ao pairar",
    "Snapshot succeeded": "Captura instant\xe2nea completa",
    "Sorry, there was a problem downloading your snapshot!": "Desculpe, houve um problema no download de sua captura instant\xe2nea!",
    "Taking snapshot - this may take a few seconds": "Efetuando captura instant\xe2nea - isso pode levar alguns instantes",
    "Toggle Spike Lines": "Habilitar/desabilitar triangula\xe7\xe3o de linhas",
    "Toggle show closest data on hover": "Habilitar/desabilitar exibi\xe7\xe3o de dado mais pr\xf3ximo ao pairar",
    "Turntable rotation": "Rota\xe7\xe3o de mesa",
    Zoom: "Zoom",
    "Zoom in": "Ampliar zoom",
    "Zoom out": "Reduzir zoom",
    "close:": "fechamento:",
    "high:": "alta:",
    "incoming flow count": "contagem de fluxo de entrada:",
    "kde:": "kde:",
    "lat:": "latitude:",
    "lon:": "longitude:",
    "low:": "baixa:",
    "lower fence:": "limite inferior:",
    "max:": "m\xe1ximo:",
    "mean \xb1 \u03c3:": "m\xe9dia \xb1 \u03c3:",
    "mean:": "m\xe9dia:",
    "median:": "mediana:",
    "min:": "m\xednimo:",
    "new text:": "novo texto:",
    "open:": "abertura:",
    "outgoing flow count:": "contagem de fluxo de sa\xedda:",
    "q1:": "q1:",
    "q3:": "q3:",
    "source": "origem:",
    "target::": "destino:",
    trace: "s\xe9rie",
    "upper fence:": "limite superior:"
  },
  format: {
    days: ["Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Ter\xe7a-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "S\xe1bado"],
    shortDays: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "S\xe1b"],
    months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Mar\xe7o", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
    shortMonths: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
    date: "%d/%m/%Y"
  }
};
"undefined" == typeof Plotly ? (window.PlotlyLocales = window.PlotlyLocales || [], window.PlotlyLocales.push(locale)) : Plotly.register(locale);'
```

I receive the following error:

> Erro: mistura de códigos de escape Unicode e octal/hexadecimal em uma cadeia de caracteres não é permitido

As I understand it, this happens because of the special characters (í, á, ã, õ, ç, etc). How can I generate the object with this mixed code?

> ex.: gr\xe1fico == gráfico

[My current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72983645/9699371) contains spelling errors as I eliminate the special characters.

> Correct mode: gráfico

> Adapted mode: grafico

This question will be useful to [finish this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72957392/9699371).

Comment: Replace *all* octal/hexadecimal escapes with Unicode ones e.g. as follows: instead erroneous `'"mean \xb1 \u03c3:": "m\xe9dia \xb1 \u03c3:"'` use `'"mean \u00b1 \u03c3:": "m\u00e9dia \u00b1 \u03c3:"'` -> returns `'"mean ± σ:": "média ± σ:"'` (exactly `[1] "\"mean ± σ:\": \"média ± σ:\""` in R console).

Comment: @JosefZ, I have answered the question based on your suggestion. Thanks! However, it was made by force, hands-on. Do you have any idea how to automate octal/hexadecimal to Unicode translation in a situation like the one in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @JosefZ's tip, in the question's comment, the manual solution for this is:

```
code  <- 'var locale = {
  moduleType: "locale",
  name: "pt-br",
  dictionary: {
    Autoscale: "Escala autom\u00E1tica",
    "Box Select": "Sele\u00E7\u00E3o retangular",
    "Click to enter Colorscale title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo da escala de cor",
    "Click to enter Component A title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do Componente A",
    "Click to enter Component B title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do Componente B",
    "Click to enter Component C title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do Componente C",
    "Click to enter Plot title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do Grafico",
    "Click to enter X axis title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do eixo X",
    "Click to enter Y axis title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do eixo Y",
    "Click to enter radial axis title": "Clique para editar o t\u00EDtulo do eixo radial",
    "Compare data on hover": "Comparar dados ao pairar",
    "Double-click on legend to isolate one trace": "Duplo clique na legenda para isolar uma s\u00E9rie",
    "Double-click to zoom back out": "Duplo clique para reverter zoom",
    "Download plot as a png": "Fazer download do gr\u00E1fico como imagem (png)",
    "Download plot": "Fazer download do gr\u00E1fico",
    "Edit in Chart Studio": "Editar no Chart Studio",
    "IE only supports svg. Changing format to svg.": "IE suporta apenas svg. Alterando formato para svg",
    "Lasso Select": "Sele\u00E7\u00E3o de lasso",
    "Orbital rotation": "Rota\u00E7\u00E3o orbital",
    Pan: "Mover",
    "Produced with Plotly": "Criado com o Plotly",
    Reset: "Restaurar",
    "Reset axes": "Restaurar eixos",
    "Reset camera to default": "Restaurar c\u00E2mera para padrao",
    "Reset camera to last save": "Restaurar c\u00E2mera para ultima salva",
    "Reset view": "Restaurar vis\u00E3o",
    "Reset views": "Restaurar vis\u00F5es",
    "Show closest data on hover": "Exibir dado mais proximo ao pairar",
    "Snapshot succeeded": "Captura instant\u00E2nea completa",
    "Sorry, there was a problem downloading your snapshot!": "Desculpe, houve um problema no download de sua captura instant\u00E2nea!",
    "Taking snapshot - this may take a few seconds": "Efetuando captura instant\u00E2nea - isso pode levar alguns instantes",
    "Toggle Spike Lines": "Habilitar/desabilitar triangula\u00E7\u00E3o de linhas",
    "Toggle show closest data on hover": "Habilitar/desabilitar exibi\u00E7ao de dado mais pr\u00F3ximo ao pairar",
    "Turntable rotation": "Rota\u00E7\u00E3o de mesa",
    Zoom: "Zoom",
    "Zoom in": "Ampliar zoom",
    "Zoom out": "Reduzir zoom",
    "close:": "fechamento:",
    "high:": "alta:",
    "incoming flow count": "contagem de fluxo de entrada:",
    "kde:": "kde:",
    "lat:": "latitude:",
    "lon:": "longitude:",
    "low:": "baixa:",
    "lower fence:": "limite inferior:",
    "max:": "m\u00E1ximo:",
    "mean \u00b1 \u03c3:": "m\u00e9dia \u00b1 \u03c3:",
    "mean:": "m\u00e9dia:",
    "median:": "mediana:",
    "min:": "m\u00EDnimo:",
    "new text:": "novo texto:",
    "open:": "abertura:",
    "outgoing flow count:": "contagem de fluxo de saida:",
    "q1:": "q1:",
    "q3:": "q3:",
    "source": "origem:",
    "target::": "destino:",
    trace: "s\u00E9rie",
    "upper fence:": "limite superior:"
  },
  format: {
    days: ["Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Ter\u00E7a-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "S\u00E1bado"],
    shortDays: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "S\u00E1b"],
    months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Mar\u00E7o", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
    shortMonths: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
    date: "%d/%m/%Y"
  }
};
"undefined" == typeof Plotly ? (window.PlotlyLocales = window.PlotlyLocales || [], window.PlotlyLocales.push(locale)) : Plotly.register(locale);'
```

I manually adjusted all octal/hexdecimal codes to Unicode.

My Unicode code reference was [ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15 Characters in Oct, Hex and HTML](https://pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html).