# Make a plotly R with interactive colors chosen by the user

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have some Shiny apps running. However, some contain graphics that may be of public interest. So, I'm looking for a solution similar to the image below, from Infogram, but where it's possible to edit the graph, especially the colors, from Poltly's (`plotly`) toolbar. Here a toy example of Infogram.

[image]

Is it possible to do something similar in Shiny R from editing Plotly? The addition of a small plot configuration button in the toolbar is ideal. If not, do you know of a similar package that would allow this?

The "top" would be:

[image]

Note the configuration button (gear) design on the toolbar. This does not exist natively.

A plotly R code example

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
fig
```

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't seem like you're new to SO, but I do want to point out this isn't a *help with my code* question. It's more like *do it for me*, which is most likely why you've not been answered thus far.

What have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't? You mentioned Shiny but included nothing to suggest that you attempted to work with Shiny to accomplish this goal.

Alright, my soap box collapsed.

This is one way out of many that you could use to accomplish this goal. At the end of my answer, I'll provide all of the code that is provided in the explanation all at once (easier copy + paste).

I've used five libraries and started with the default Plotly colors.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(colourpicker)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# starting plot with default colors from Plotly
defCol <- c('#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', 
            '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf')
```

Next, I wrote a UDF to create a color select/picker for each label in the boxplot. The comments in the code should make this self-explanatory. However, if you have any questions about this or any part of the answer, let me know. (I know what I meant...that doesn't mean anyone else does.)

The input value, or as I refer to it in the code-feature names, are the names you'll see in the legend. It's a vector of the unique values of whatever column you have assigned to `color` in `plot_ly()`. In this answer, it is `unique(midwest$state)`.

```
colInput <- function(vecFeats) { # vecFeats = vector of feature names for colors
  pickers <- invisible(lapply(1:length(vecFeats), function(k) {
    colourInput(inputId = paste0("col", k),           # names used in plot_ly()
                label = vecFeats[k],                  # color sel label for user
                value = defCol[k],    # initial color == this should match initial plot
                showColour = "background"  # to user, only show the color itself after select
    )
    }))
pickers
}
```

I created an object that has the plot labels next because it gets used repeatedly. Note the comments I've made about sorting and using a character field versus a factor (or ordered) field.

```
# used multiple times-- the data color names
dcn <- sort(unique(midwest$state))  # not a factor, alphabetize to match plot
#-- Plotly will alphabetize if not factor --
```

Next is the Shiny user interface and server. In the UI, I've called the UDF, `colInput()`, in the call for the `sidebar`. I added the plot rendering output, `plotlyOutput`, to the `body`. In the server, I've only called for the plot rendering, using the `input$col` + a number for the colors. This is the interaction from the user input in the sidebar. The initial colors are those established in the UDF (`value = defCol[k]`).

```
ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(      # create aesthetics
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Header"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(                 # create mask for user interaction
      collapsed = F,
      title = "Choose colors for the plot.",  # sidebar title
      .list = colInput(dcn)                   # use data color names, call UDF
      ),
  body = dashboardBody(title = "Body", plotlyOutput("plt"))
)

server <- function (input, output, session) {
  # using same data for color selects and plot
  output$plt <- renderPlotly({                      # send plot to ui
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, 
            # connect colors to color picker in sidebar dynamically
            colors = paste0("input$col", 1:length(dcn)) %>%   # use data color names
              map(., function(i) {eval(parse(text = i))}) %>% # convert strings to obj
              unlist() %>% setNames(dcn),           # make named list for Plotly
            type = "box")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

All the code above altogether.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(colourpicker)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# starting plot with default colors from Plotly
defCol <- c('#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', 
            '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf')

# create color selectors for plot, using plot data
colInput <- function(vecFeats) { # vecFeats = vector of feature names for colors
  pickers <- invisible(lapply(1:length(vecFeats), function(k) {
    colourInput(inputId = paste0("col", k),           # names used in plot_ly()
                label = vecFeats[k],                  # color sel label for user
                value = defCol[k],    # initial color == this should match initial plot
                showColour = "background"  # to user, only show the color itself after select
    )
    }))
pickers
}

# used multiple times-- the data color names
dcn <- sort(unique(midwest$state))  # not a factor, alphabetize to match plot
#-- Plotly will alphabetize if not factor --

ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(      # create aesthetics
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Header"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(                 # create mask for user interaction
      collapsed = F,
      title = "Choose colors for the plot.",  # sidebar title
      .list = colInput(dcn)                   # use data color names, call UDF
      ),
  body = dashboardBody(title = "Body", plotlyOutput("plt"))
)

server <- function (input, output, session) {
  # using same data for color selects and plot
  output$plt <- renderPlotly({                      # send plot to ui
    plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, 
            # connect colors to color picker in sidebar dynamically
            colors = paste0("input$col", 1:length(dcn)) %>%   # use data color names
              map(., function(i) {eval(parse(text = i))}) %>% # convert strings to obj
              unlist() %>% setNames(dcn),           # make named list for Plotly
            type = "box")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your idea is good. But I don't want to add this information to Shiny's sidebar. I would like a solution that adds the plot configuration option to the Plotly toolbar. I've had a few failed attempts, nothing that adds value.

Comment: There are an immense amount of options available within Plotly and other graphing packages. Your comment, as well as your question, are ambiguous, suggesting that perhaps you would rather do it yourself. Take a look at [Plotly's buttons' options](https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/). Colors, type, symbols, and many other plot elements can be UI, not in the `modebar` per se, but it could look as if they were.

Comment: My question doesn't involve sidebar or button like the link you sent. I want to add the plot color configuration option in the toolbar. This probably involves hacking and JS development.

Comment: Here's an example of how fix something inside plotly. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72957392/9699371